# A way to override what 'type()' reports

Tags: python, string, class, casting, repr

Is there a way to alter a CLASS OBJECT so that `type(object)` reports a custom string?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        if 'detector' in t:
            my_type_string = "I am set as a detector."
        else:
            my_type_string = "I am set as a broadcaster."

>>> o = MyClass('detector')
>>> type(o)
I am set as a detector.
```

Comment: `type(..)` does **not** return a string...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not do that. Instead you should implement two separate classes, both of which inherit from `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    my_type_string = "I am not set to anything."

    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_type_string

class Detector(MyClass):
    my_type_string = "I am set as a detector."

class Broadcaster(MyClass):
    my_type_string = "I am set as a broadcaster."

>>> o = Detector()
>>> type(o)
__main__.Detector
>>> str(o)
'I am set as a detector.'
```

And if you want to switch your class depending on a string you provide you could implement a factory that returns the desired object:

```
def factory(t):
    if 'detector' in t:
        return Detector()
    else:
        return Broadcaster()

>>> o = factory('detector')
>>> type(o)
__main__.Detector
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it is dangerous. `type` is a builtin, and other places could use it. But if you know what you are doing and why you do it, you can redefine `type`. but **Here be dragons. You've been warned.**:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        if 'detector' in t:
            self.my_type_string = "I am set as a detector."
        else:
            self.my_type_string = "I am set as a broadcaster."

def type(obj):
    return obj.my_type_string if isinstance(obj, MyClass) else __builtins__.type(obj)
```

But IMHO, you should not use the builtin `type` name for that use, but create a specific function:

```
def my_type(obj):
    return obj.my_type_string if hasattr(obj, 'my_type_string') else str(type(obj))
```

because now it can consistently return a string

Comment: Shouldn't it be `obj.my_type_string`?

Comment: Redefining `type` is not a good idea, and I'm surprised to see a 50k+ rep user even suggesting that.  –1.

Comment: @wim It is possible, and language allows it. I said first *it is dangerous*, and I later added *you should not use the builtin name `type`*. I do not know what are OP requirement (even if **I** would never do it...)

Comment: So, there is no point to even mention it.  Sometimes you have to see the question behind the question.

Comment: @wim: That's the reason why I have suggested to use another name. But the fact is that a dynamic language like Python allows builtins redefinition. It is even a powerful language feature, like are metaclasses and decorators, that all allow *special* behaviour. Anyway, I agree that it should not be used here.